# How to return the user to same page after logging out in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have routes that are accessible for guest and authenticated users but the thing is how to return the logged in users back to the same page and not to the home page after clicking the logging out button?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am looking for a build in functionality to handle that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stay on the same page after a logout in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210822/how-to-stay-on-the-same-page-after-a-logout-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the issue as @onix said. just add a hidden input and check if it exits in the logout method.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    if($request->has('go_back')) {
         return redirect()->back();
    }
    return redirect('/');
}

<form action="{{ route('signout') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @if(\Route::current()->getName() == 'freedom'))
        <input type="hidden" name="go_back">
    @endif
    <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Comment: so this including sessions, extra inputs, extra variables, is better?

Comment: no it is just for demonstration. You will only need a go back input.

Comment: that will make sure the user will not get redirected in all cases as you said before.

Answer (score 0):

> *assuming you use auth.

1. Go to: `your_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ AuthenticatesUsers.php`
2. Find `logout` function and just change the return to `back();`

But u think its bad practice as you may send the user back to an unauthorized page and he will get an error exception.

Comment: Yea, I have a better solution for that. just a second.

Comment: Vendor files should not be modified.

Comment: I agree if you do not know what are you doing.